# Is it possible to install the latest version of ghc using cabal?

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal

I hope the title is self explanatory. I can't seem to find a ghc package on hackage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you cannot. However, you can install from binaries or compile it from source (this requires that you have an older GHC to compile it with). You can get tarballs from [the GHC home page](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/).

Comment: I thought this was the case, but it's great to have a definitive answer, thanks.